# Shadows material design Android(XML)

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I am very much noob to android , can anyone please tell me the ways to implement drop shadows as per the designs and parameters of shadows in adobe xd in my android application

Example design

[image]

Just have a look at the search and veg only buttons. i want a shadow like this.

Comment: Set some elevation on the UI elements that you want to have a shadow, such as via `android:elevation` in the layout resource.

Comment: But bro If I add..there will be shadows on all the side, what if designer wants me to put shadows only on left or in left and bottom,actually that's where I am not able to figure it out

Comment: "what if designer wants me to put shadows only on left or in left and bottom" -- the designer should adhere to Material Design's approach for shadows, so your app better matches other apps. Otherwise, the designer will need to give you some gradient that represents the shadow, and you would need to add that to the background for your affected widgets.

Comment: Drop shadows in Android aren't really configurable.  If you don't like what elevation does, you either need to implement things yourself, or you need to push back against your UX designer.  This is a regular fight I have with designers.  Generally its a winnable one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.